# Data Change Notification performance impact

Tags: java, oracle

I built a simple application that is monitoring Oracle's DB on a single table. I tried to test performance impact of enabled subscription and was unpleased surprised that degradation is about x2 for inserting about 10000 records each in standalone transaction.

- without subscription 10k insert ~ 30 sec
- with subscription ROWID granularity  10k insert ~ 60 sec

If I set:

OracleConnection.DCN_NOTIFY_ROWIDS, "false"
OracleConnection.DCN_QUERY_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION, "false"

then all degradation is vanishing but I need to get details of updates.
I removed all extra processing from client side so this is all about subscription overhead.

I am wondering is it so expensive by nature or I can tune this somehow?

Comment: so your question why when adding notification to false , the performance enhanced ?

Comment: no, question is why it became so slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database change notification has an overhead during commit. This can't be tuned. Note that this feature is designed for read-mostly tables that are worth being cached on the client/mid-tier. One trick might be to unregister your app during batch inserts.